# How do I create multiple plots from an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: import, excel, procedural-programming

I have imported an Excel spreadsheet with dimensions {row, col}= {92, 28} into Mathematica, I want to plot 27 datasets from the spreadsheet: column 1 with column 2, column 1 with column 3, ..., column 1 with column 27.

Is there any single expression with which I can plot these 27 graphs rather then doing one-by-one?

With following answer:

[Multiple curves plot from excel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121472/multiple-curves-)

I have been able to plot in one dataset, but I need each dataset plotted separately.

Here is a link to my excel file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/k58p6bua4megojn/1-Mode.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = Import["1-Mode.xlsx"][[1]];
plotlist = Table[
  ListLinePlot[a[[All, {1, i}]]],
  {i, 2, Dimensions[a][[2]]}]
```

This assumes that the file `"1-Mode.xlsx"` lies in the current directory. Use a full path instead if this is not the case.

Comment: Thank you, That is, what I want. Further How can I do 2nd order polynomial fit to each graph. And show both polynomial fit and actual graph at each graph. And also 2nd order differential of polynomial fit.
Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Technically, this is a new questions. Anyways, you can find a polynomial fit with `FindFit`, plot it with `Plot`, and show the plot together with the `ListLinePlot` from above with `Show`. The second derivative can be obtained with `D`. I'd suggest to study the documentations of these symbols first.